# How to make inner elements of a container not able to be clickable and selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement a loading state where when we click on the button, we make the container opacity to .32 and we shouldn't be able to click or select the elements inside the container. In the example below, the inner `a` tag is still clickable and selectable after the loading is shown.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const btn = document.getElementById('load');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add('loading');
})
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: tomato;
}

.loading {
  opacity: .32;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <a href="www.google.com">Test</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">Test</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">Test</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">Test</a>
</div>

<button id="load">
  Load
</button>
```

Comment: Use "event.stopPropagation" and "event.preventDefault()", its can help you. help: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php?msclkid=c8f7544ecf7f11ec80e68dcad0a7648c

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into using `pointer-events: none;` from CSS? See running snippet below.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const btn = document.getElementById('load');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add('loading');
})
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: tomato;
}

.loading {
  opacity: .32;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <a href="www.google.com">Test</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">Test</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">Test</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">Test</a>
</div>

<button id="load">
  Load
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is, disabling the anchor tag. For this, you can simply use the following property in the CSS: `pointer-events: none;`.

With this even if the anchor tag is clicked, nothing will happen.